# Use a cell value (text) as a part of a formula in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, cell, formula

I have a problem while doing a macro in Excel VBA which looks simple but I was not able to find an answer.

What I want is to change a formula depending on a value of a concrete cell; the cell is situated in C7 and can have the text OR or the text AND. The part of the formula is (being CritEUs and CritSKUs String variables):

```
If CritEUs = "NO" (OR/AND) CritSKUs = "NO" Then .... (whatever)
```

So I want to change the OR/AND depending on the value in C7, I tried to use INDIRECT but I think it works only with numbers, and also the following (being W the Worksheet variable):

```
Dim Pattern As String

Pattern = W.Range("C7").Value

If CritEUs = "NO" " & Pattern & " CritSKUs = "NO" Then
```

But the Excel don't accept me this option.

Could it be that this is not possible?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: I'd suggest to "hard code" this into your if clause: `If (Cells(7,3).Value = "AND" AND (CritEUs = "NO" AND CritSKUs = "NO")) OR (Cells(7,3).Value = "OR" AND (CritEUs = "NO" OR CritSKUs = "NO")) Then ...`

Comment: It works perfectly! A good logical way to put all in only one condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look to handle this in another if statement and then nest the next if statement within like so:

```
Sub Example()

Dim Pattern As String

Pattern = W.Range("C7").Value

If Pattern = "AND" Then
    If CritEUs = "NO" And CritSKUs = "NO" Then
        'Do Something'
    End If
ElseIf Pattern = "OR" Then
    If CritEUs = "NO" Or CritSKUs = "NO" Then
        'Do Something'
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is perfect and understandable, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I **strongly prefer** Gareth's solution, there is a trick for doing what you want (i.e. for evaluating the condition) through the usage of the `Application.Evaluate()` method. It would be:

```
If Application.Evaluate(Pattern & "(" & Chr(34) & CritEUs & Chr(34) & "=" & Chr(34) & "NO" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & CritSKUs & Chr(34) & "=" & Chr(34) & "NO" & Chr(34) & ")") Then
```

... where the string being an expression such as `=AND(whatever = "NO", whateverelse = "NO")` or `=OR(whatever = "NO", whateverelse = "NO")` (depending on the value of the variable `Pattern`) that can be evaluated by the MS Excel application no matter what the system language is.

But as I said, I would personally prefer a nested if block as Gareth suggested because it's clearer what you are doing and it cannot crash if the user inserts an invalid logic operator or makes just a spelling mistake; you should consider this option if you don't want / cannot slightly re-design your code.

**FORMULA EXPLANATION - required from the asker**

The `Evaluate()` is a method of the `Application` object, which means of the object `MS Excel`. This method is very straightforward:

```
input: string
output: evaluation of the string
```

It is in fact used to "evaluate" a string inserted by the user **exactly as it does when you type a formula into a cell**. If you type into a cell "=3+4", you are basically typing `Application.Evaluate("3+4")`. This will return you `7`, because it's the result of the string evaluation you provided.

This built-in is very very powerful, because it uses a very consolidated system (the one of MS Excel) to parse and evaluate *any string that Excel can evaluate*. Moreover, the evaluation is always in English (you can use the English function `IF` but not the Italian `SE`, nor the German `WENN` or the French `SI` because the method evaluates *as if your Excel was in English* to be system independent.

On the other hand, the `Chr(34)` is just returning the character `"`. This character is *hard* to use in VBA because it's usually need to separate strings (e.g. a = `"first" & "second"`. However, you need this character *inside the string to be evaluated* so I'm just calling it with `Chr(34)` to avoid confusion of the compiler.

SUMMARY:

The string is being built up like this:

```
Pattern & "(" & Chr(34) & CritEUs & Chr(34) & "=" & Chr(34) & "NO" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & CritSKUs & Chr(34) & "=" & Chr(34) & "NO" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Being...

```
Pattern = AND or OR
Chr(34) = "
```

... the string that we are building will be of this kind (just a possible outcome):

```
"AND("NO"="NO","YES"="NO")"
```

So, once we have built-up this string, we pass it into the `Evaluate` method: it's like if we were writing `=AND("NO"="NO","YES"="NO")` into an Excel cell. What would the outcome be? Clearly it depends on your variable, but in this case it would be `FALSE`, so the `If - Then` block will not be entered because the return value is false. Otherwise, it would be entered.

This is not a "wrong" method, but as I was saying it has only two possible downsides:

1) It needs data validation, because if you pass crap into the variable `Pattern` the `Evaluate` method will fail; in Gareth's solution, instead, only `AND` and `OR` will be evaluated, otherwise the code will skip --> more stability;

2) It's not 100% intuitive: while Gareth's solution could be explained to a 10 year old child (because it's very very straight-forward to understand), this one needs (as we just did) a deeper analysis to understand properly what it does. I.E.: you need one line of code to write it, but you/someone else that will have to work on it in the future will need 5-10 minutes and a cup of coffee to understand what the statement wants to check.

Comment: Nice trick! If this method is used, Data Validation should be used in cell C7 to only allow inputs of "AND" or "OR".

Comment: @TheEngineer I strongly agree with you, that's why I say that I would personally pick Gareth's solution, but I understand there might be some different need of not expanding/redesigning the code.

Comment: You were the only one that solved this in the way I was asking (although maybe I will use the others as they are more intuitive), but your explanation is very clear. In theory there should be no mistake using yours as the C7 cell has a drop-down list and there are only two options. 

Could you please explain me briefly what is Application.Evaluate? And also the Chr(34)? Because I understood what the function does but not how it works. 

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @JoanAlbert, I added an explanation, don't hesitate to ask me if you need some more.

Comment: I can just say: impressive! You are the best, thank you very much for the explanation.